# Hibernate Reverse Engineering with Eclipse and MySql

Tags: mysql, database, eclipse, hibernate

I'm having the hardest time getting Eclipse to connect and reverse engineer from a MySQL5 database. I can see Eclipse connecting to my MySQL database and can even see the tables through the "Data Source Explorer" view but when I try it after creating Hibernate Console and Configuration files, I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException:
Problems while loading database
    driverclass (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
Problems while loading database
    driverclass (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

From my simple java project, I start by creating a Hibernate Configuration File (cfg.xml).

```
Name of file: hibernate.cfg.xml
Session Factory name: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
Database Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect      
Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver      
Connection Url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<myDatabaseName>    
Default Schema: <myDatabaseName>        
Username: correct username  
Password: correct password
```

I also have selected the option to "Create a console Configuration"

At this point, I can see the new configuration listed in my "Hibernate Configuration" perspective/workbench pane. If I try to expand it, I get the earlier listed error.

I don't understand why I can see the database through the 'Data Source Explorer" and even though I'm using the DB connection profile listed in there as part of my configuration, I still get this error.

I also tried to create a new database profile using a manual mysql connector jar (mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar) and same end result.

Versions of what I have:

```
Eclipse version: 3.6.0 aka Helios, Build 20100617 - 1415
MySQL: 5.1.34
Hibernate Tools (from JBoss): HibernateTools-3.3.1.v201006011046R-H111-GA 
(placed into Eclipse's 'dropins' folder)
```

What am I doing wrong in my hibernate configuration setup?

Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Hibernate Console Configuration doesn't have the MySQL JDBC driver on its classpath, hence the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. From the reference guide of the Hibernate Tools:

> ### [3.4. Creating a Hibernate Console Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/#console_conf)
>
> ...
>
> [alt text http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/images/plugins/plugins_3.png](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html_single/images/plugins/plugins_3.png)
>
> ...
>
> - *Classpath*: The classpath for loading POJO and JDBC drivers; only needed if
>     the default classpath of the Project
>     does not contain the required classes.
>     Do not add Hibernate core libraries or
>     dependencies, they are already
>     included. If you get ClassNotFound
>     errors then check this list for
>     possible missing or redundant
>     directories/jars.
> - *Include default classpath from project*: When enabled the project
>     classpath will be appended to the
>     classpath specified above

Does the "associated project" have the MySQL JDBC driver declared as library? If not, then you must add it (either as a project library or in the above tab).